# Asterisk Call Manager/1.1 Response: Error Message: Missing action in request

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to install / configure [asterisk-gui](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+GUI) for my asterisk server (first time, I am a newbie on asterisk).

I have run all the make scripts, and `make checkconfig` returns ok.

```
 --- Checking Asterisk configuration to see if it will support the GUI ---
* Checking for http.conf: OK
* Checking for manager.conf: OK
* Checking if HTTP is enabled: OK
* Checking if HTTP static support is enabled: OK
* Checking if manager is enabled: OK
* Checking if manager over HTTP is enabled: OK
 --- Everything looks good ---  
 * GUI should be available at http://siddharth-desktop:8088/asterisk/static/config/index.html 

 * Note: If you have bindaddr=127.0.0.1 in /etc/asterisk/http.conf 
   you will only be able to visit it from the local machine. 

   Example: http://localhost:8088/asterisk/static/config/index.html

 * The login and password should be an entry from /etc/asterisk/manager.conf
   which has 'config' permission in read and write.  For example:

    [admin]
    secret = mysecret4942
    read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,config
    write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,config

 --- Good luck! ---
```

Contents of /etc/asterisk/http.conf

```
[general]
enabled=yes
enablestatic=yes
bindaddr=127.0.0.1
```

Contents of /etc/asterisk/manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled=yes
webenabled=yes
[admin]
    secret=<MYPASSWORD>
    read=system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,config,read,write,originate
    write=system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,config,read,write,originate

port=5038
bindaddr=127.0.0.1
```

**Problem 1**

When I use `127.0.0.1:5038/asterisk/static/config/index.html` on Chrome, I get the error

> > Asterisk Call Manager/1.1 Response: Error Message: Missing action in request

**Problem 2**

When I insert the line `bindport=5038` to http.conf. I get a error

> > Not Found
> >
> > The requested URL was not found on this server.

**Possible Problem Areas**

- User name : jsiddharth (not admin as suggested in the manager.conf), is this the problem ?
- I get a error when I load `sudo asterisk -c`. Is there a issue with some modules ? I know chan_mobile does not load, but that should not impact the gui right ?

Log

```
  [Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: cdr.c:1582 do_reload: CDR simple logging enabled.
  [Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: loader.c:1176 load_modules: 179 modules will be loaded.
 .[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: res_smdi.c:1418 load_module: No SMDI interfaces are available to listen on, not starting SMDI listener.
......[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:418 load_dynamic_module: Error loading module 'res_crypto': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_crypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:894 load_resource: Module 'res_crypto' could not be loaded.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:481 load_dynamic_module: Error loading module 'chan_iax2.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/chan_iax2.so: undefined symbol: ast_aes_set_encrypt_key
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:894 load_resource: Module 'chan_iax2.so' could not be loaded.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:418 load_dynamic_module: Error loading module 'res_crypto': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_crypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:894 load_resource: Module 'res_crypto' could not be loaded.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:481 load_dynamic_module: Error loading module 'func_aes.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/func_aes.so: undefined symbol: ast_aes_set_encrypt_key
[Jun  3 23:23:58] WARNING[5250]: loader.c:894 load_resource: Module 'func_aes.so' could not be loaded.
.......[Jun  3 23:23:58] ERROR[5250]: chan_mobile.c:4537 load_module: No Bluetooth devices found. Not loading module.
.[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: chan_skinny.c:7260 config_load: Configuring skinny from skinny.conf
......................................................[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:164 pbx_load_module: Starting AEL load process.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:177 pbx_load_module: AEL load process: parsed config file name '/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael'.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:180 pbx_load_module: AEL load process: checked config file name '/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael'.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:187 pbx_load_module: AEL load process: compiled config file name '/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael'.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:192 pbx_load_module: AEL load process: merged config file name '/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael'.
[Jun  3 23:23:58] NOTICE[5250]: pbx_ael.c:195 pbx_load_module: AEL load process: verified config file name '/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael'.
.........................................................................    -- Invalid license key!
..  == Aliased CLI command 'hangup request' to 'channel request hangup'
  == Aliased CLI command 'originate' to 'channel originate'
  == Aliased CLI command 'help' to 'core show help'
  == Aliased CLI command 'pri intense debug span' to 'pri set debug 2 span'
  == Aliased CLI command 'reload' to 'module reload'
.............................. ]
Asterisk Ready.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cryptic it is :), the issue was I was pointing to the wrong path.

```
http://-local_host-:5038/asterisk/static/config/index.html
```

Here `asterisk` refers to the setting in `http.conf`

> > ;prefix=asterisk

It was commented. So the correct path actually should be

```
http://-local_host-:5038/static/config/index.html
```

Yet did not work. So on a crazy hunch, I removed the port and bindaddr from http.conf completely and only set the ip and port in the manager.conf.

```
[general]
enabled=yes
enablestatic=yes
#bindaddr=0.0.0.0 # allow GUI to be accessible from all IP addresses.
bindaddr=127.0.0.1 # require access from the machine Asterisk is running on
bindport=5039
```

And changed the path to (without `asterisk` prefix and change in port number)

```
http://-local_host-:5039/static/config/index.html
```

[This](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+GUI) link helped.

**It worked !!!**